# Save value of inputfield into varialbe

Tags: typescript, react-native

I am trying to build a very basic LogIn screen atm as a starter project for the future.

All is done in TypeScript and React Native.

When i try to use OnChangeText function, email is not set to the value that was put into the field and the console.log remains "I am [object Object]"

How do i parse the input value correctly into the variable to use properly in the upcoming code?

sorry for this very basic question, i followed a tutorial that was more or less frontend only and now it seems i am stuck with the first step of the backend :/

If i understand it right, the useState hook should declare email as a string (hence the '') and then use setEmail to enter the given value into email. The (email) that is given with onCahngeText is not this variable but the value of the inputfield?

```
export default function App() {

  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  return (
    <LoginWrapper>

      <Text>Enter UserName</Text>
      <LoginInput
        style={styles.text}
        placeholder="username/email"
        onChangeText={(email) => {
          setEmail(email)
          console.log("I am " + email)
        }} />
      <Text>Enter Password</Text>

      <LoginInput
        style={styles.text}
        secureTextEntry
        placeholder="Password"
        onChangeText={(password) => setPassword(password)} />

    </LoginWrapper>
  );
}
```

EDIT: i found it to be working half right now with changing the name of the input from email to input

```
onChangeText={(input) => {
          setEmail(input)
        }}
```

but the mobile keyboard closes after a single value is put in. I can´t write "Hello", as only "H" gets through. Is this maybe jsut a sideeffect of using Expo?

EDIT: The code for LoginInput

```
const LoginInput = styled.TextInput`
    //styling
`
```

Comment: Please add LoginInput code

Comment: Can you please show the import of the styled object

Answer (score 0):

If I remember it correctly the `onChangeText` event returns an event handler object. So your code should be:

```
<LoginInput
    style={styles.text}
    placeholder="username/email"
    onChangeText={event => {
        setEmail(event.target.value)
    }} 
/>
```

This will work if your `LoginInput` component is a regular `<input>`.

Comment: it is a <TextInput>

Comment: Dear mate, this is React Native but not React. There is no <input />

Comment: The onChange onChangeText methods work similarly dear mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of doing it properly: https://snack.expo.dev/@zvona/onchangetext-example

You can refer to `useState` set functions directly by passing them to `onChangeText` event handler since it's first callback parameter is the value from **TextInput**. `useEffect` hook is for displaying the results.

Here is the source code of the example:

```
const App = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`Email: ${email}, password: ${password}`);
  }, [email, password]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.LoginWrapper}>
      <Text>Enter UserName</Text>
      <TextInput placeholder="username/email" onChangeText={setEmail} />
      <Text>Enter Password</Text>

      <TextInput
        secureTextEntry
        placeholder="Password"
        onChangeText={setPassword}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: this results in an infinite rerender exeption

Comment: @fghjkl you mean in Expo Snack or in your code? I couldn't see the actual problem unless you're altering / re-rendering email+password variables somewhere else